# Running vagrant inside VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, vagrant

I'm running Xubuntu 14.04 in a VirtualBox VM on Windows 7. Inside the VM, I want to use Vagrant as part of my development environment. The Vagrant setup executes successfully, until it wants the VM (inside the VM) to boot. After a few minutes, it fails with a timeout. Then running `vagrant ssh` fails with `ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer`.

I've found several questions on SO, SF and here that mention this error, but none of them seem to match my case.

I'd be glad if one of you know what the problem is, and even more if you know how to solve it!

Comment: My sysadmin tells me not to try and run a VM in a VM. We ended up running the Vagrant setup on the host machine, and connecting to it from the Xubuntu VM.

Comment: [Can you run one virtual machine inside another?](http://superuser.com/questions/312433/can-you-run-one-virtual-machine-inside-another)

Comment: sure, you *can*. Doesn't mean it's worth the trouble.

Comment: Use Vagrant from within Windows, or use a dual boot solution with another ubuntu as host for Vagrant. ^^-d

Comment: Virtualbox VMs don't get the hardware virtualization acceleration, which is required to boot VMs in 64 bit mode or with more  than one virtual CPU.  Sticking to 32-bit uniprocessors in the nested VMs may help.

Comment: Simple, check your private key using `vagrant ssh-config` and with this, check public key inside VM Or re-setup  vagrant insecure key.